# Jquery tab not showing first child selected

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm not able to select the first child using jquery tabs.

```
 $( function() {
    $( "#twocoltabs" ).tabs();
    $( "#twocoltabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 0 );
    $( "#twocoltabs" ).tabs( "option", "disabled", [1] );
  });
```

Nothing is working

```
$( function() {
        $( "#twocoltabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Even this script shows the second child selected.

```
$('#twocoltabs li:first-child').addClass('active');
```

This only show the tab name selected not content and both of tab name are selected if I add this.

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with plugins and frameworks needed to show the issue

Comment: Are you sure it should be `$( "#twocoltabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 0 )` from the documentation it looks to me like it should be `$( "#twocoltabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 )`